# Segue from custom UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a custom `UIBarButtonItem` using `UIView` and `UIImageView` inside it. Following is the code for creating and `UIBarButtonItem` to navigation bar

```
    let containView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40))

    let imageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(45, 5, 27, 27))
    imageview.image = UIImage(named: "giftbox-icon")
    imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    containView.addSubview(imageview)

    let circleImageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(61, 1, 17, 17))
    circleImageview.image = UIImage(named: "red-circle")
    circleImageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    containView.addSubview(circleImageview)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(60, 1, 20, 15))
    label.text = String(cartQty)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(11)
    containView.addSubview(label)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containView)
```

This makes it appear like this

[image]

Now I want that, when a user taps over this `UIBarButtonItem` a segue to another view controller should happen. How can I associate an action programatically to this using Swift?

Comment: It might be easier to create an image from the drawing because you can't specify an action using `UIBarButtonItem(customView:)`. Otherwise you have to implement that the `UIView` handles the user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension of UIBarButtonItem as below in Swift.

```
import UIKit

extension UIBarButtonItem {
    func addTargetWithAct(target: AnyObject, action: Selector) {
        self.target = target
        self.action = action
    }
}
```

and change the below code

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containView)
```

to

```
var barbuttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containView);
barbuttonItem.addTargetForAction(self, action:    Selector("mySelectorName"))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barbuttonItem
```

where "mySelectorName" is your action method.

I did not excuted this. Check and fix any compile issue.

UPDATE:-
  as per apple docs the above solution may not work.
  Use the below solution instead,

```
UIButton *btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40)
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(mySelectorName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
containView.addSubview(btn)
```

Comment: Additional to my other comment from the documentation: *UIBarButtonItem(customView:) - The bar button item created by this method **does not call the action method of its target** in response to user interactions.*

Answer (score 1):

Replace `UIButton` instead of `UIView`. Like

```
let containView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
containView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40)
containView.addTarget(self, action: "yourButtonEvent", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
//...........
// ........ Add all your content
```

and implement method

```
func yourButtonEvent() {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourDestControllerIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are having Custom view for UIBarButtonItem , implement a tap gesture on containView and with in tap action/method put at the end of the method

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueID", sender: nil) // replace segue id from storyboard
```

override below method if you need any properties to be initialized on second view controller (Note: import second view controller header file)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let secondController = segue.destinationViewController as UISecondViewController
    // you can initialize some properties on second view controller instance before performing segue
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your action just use `performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender: nil)`

Comment: can you explain it a bit more?